# Column in list from include sequelize

Tags: sql, join, sequelize.js

provided that I have following statement in `sequelize`

```
return models.VehicleModel
            .findAll({
                include: [
                    {
                        attributes: ['id'],
                        model: models.Unit
                    },
                    {
                        model: models.myPattern,
                        where: {
                            VehicleModelId: { $in: data.VehicleModelIds }
                        },
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: models.Calendar,
                                include: [
                                    {
                                        model: models.Restrictions,
                                        include: [
                                            {
                                                model: models.RestrictionType
                                            }],
                                        where: {
                                            //THIS IS THE LINE I NEED TO CHANGE SOMEHOW
                                            UnitId: { $in: [models.Unit.id] }
                                        },
                                        required: false
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                where: {
                    id: { $in: data.VehicleModelIds }
                }
            })
```

This gives me `NULL` in the query like so:

```
[myPattern.Calendar.Restrictions].UnitId IN (NULL) AND ....
```

I want to be able to get the following instead:

```
[myPattern.Calendar.Restrictions].UnitId IN (Units.id) AND ....
```

This is because they are not mandatory to be there but should of course be linked to the proper unit corresponding to the vehicle model.

The `myPattern` is linked to the `Calendar` who is in turn linked to the `Restrictions` and so to the `Units`.
This all using `id` column.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found it**

So for people looking for the **"how to"**:

```
//...
where: {
    UnitId: { $in: [models.sequelize.literal('Units.id')] },
}
//...and so on
```

This will output in the query: `[myPattern.Calendar.Restrictions].UnitId IN (Units.id)`